# Loss of nameref when changing documentclass

Tags: memoir, cleveref, nameref

The following MWE compiles fine

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\newtcbtheorem{thm}{Theorem}{#1}{thm}

\begin{document}
  
  This is a reference to \nameref{thm:awesome} labelled \ref{thm:awesome}%
  
  \begin{thm}[fonttitle=\sffamily\bfseries\normalsize]{My awesome test theorem}{awesome}
    Isn't this theorem so awesome?
  \end{thm}
  
\end{document}
```

When I switch to `memoir` `documentclass`, I get the following output (using `nameref` instead of `cleverref` is the same)…
[image]

Any idea to solve this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems `memoir`'s hyperref settings aren't properly in sync anymore. Or at least it cannot pickup the title from `tcolorbox`.

You can bring back the proper `\nameref` via

```
\makeatletter
\RenewDocumentCommand\nameref{s}
    {\IfBooleanTF{#1}{\@namerefstar}{\T@nameref}}
\makeatother
```

in the preamble (after loading the packages)

Comment: Thank you so much, I couldn't have found it on my own!